# get Biggest collection in a collection of collection

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a Collection of collection.

I would like to get the biggest collection inside the collection.

I wrote a function that works well, but I'm pretty sure it can be done much quicker:

```
private function getMaxFightersByEntity($userGroups): int
{
    $max = 0;
    foreach ($userGroups as $userGroup) { // $userGroup is another Collection
        if (count($userGroup) > $max) {
            $max = count($userGroup);
        }
    }
    return $max;
}
```

I'm quite sure there is a better way managing collection, but don't really know it.

Anyone has a better solution???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the collection by the count of the inner collections, and then just take the first item (largest group).

```
// sortByDesc: sort the groups by their size, largest first
// first: get the first item in the result: the largest group
// count: get the size of the largest group
return $userGroups
    ->sortByDesc(function ($group) {
        return $group->count();
    })
    ->first()
    ->count();
```

It won't be "quicker" than your current solution in execution time, but it is written to take advantage of the functions provided by collections.

Comment: I like it! Will probably do it this way